# UploadField reinitialised after DOM update

Tags: ajax, webpack, ecmascript-6, silverstripe, jquery-file-upload

I have a form with an `UploadField`. We submitted via ajax and then on completion the form is returned from the backend and added back into the page without a page reload.

This works fine however we now are moving to ES6 (from ES5) with webpack and while the form is replaced, the `UploadField` isn't reinitialised and therefore no longer works correctly.

We do run two jQueries however I don't think this is the problem as no errors are thrown when updating the DOM. I've also looked at initialising the field manually however I haven't had much luck and am not sure where Entwine fits in the mix of it. Whats the best way to get the `UploadField` working correctly after an AJAX update?